# Android: How to create this simple layout?

Tags: android, layout

I need to create a simple layout with two form widgets (for example - two buttons). The first one must fill all available width of the parent layout and the second one must have some fixed size.

That's what I need: [image]

If I set FILL_PARENT to the first widget - I don't see the second one. It just blows away from a view area of the layout :) I don't know how to fix this...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using `layout_weight` with `LinearLayout`. Notice the width of the first TextView is `"0dp"`, which means "ignore me and use the weight". The weight can be any number; since it's the only weighted view, it will expand to fill available space.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that with a RelativeLayout or a FrameLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="#ccccee"
        android:text="A label. I need to fill all available width." />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:background="#aaddee"
        android:text=">>" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: How the layout looks]