# How to create a fixed/dynamic width column layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view

I am trying to build a View (ideally a LinearLayout) that matches its parent width. This layout is supposed to have 2 children (horizontally):

1. A TextView that is supposed take up all of the available width - or at least wrap its content (but in no case overlap the other view).
2. An other LinearLayout that has a fixed width of 60dp.

Here is a basic sketch of what I'm trying to achieve: [image: sketch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13096242/752320). Just swap the second TextView in that answer with your child LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView Multiline"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#0000ff" >
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10dp"/>        
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

though 60 dp is really narrow imho